# Multiple nested if in google sheets returning FALSE

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api

I am trying to make a spreadsheet for my scouts.  I want to be able to put in their grade, and it to return their designated rank.  I have looked up how to use multiple IF statements, and how to use the IFS statement.  It either returns a #N/A or a FALSE whenever I put anything OTHER than the first statement.

This is the nested IF statement

`=IF(J5="K","Lion", IF(J5="1","Tiger", IF(J5="2","Wolf", IF(J5="3","Bear", IF(J5="4","Webelos I", IF(J5="5","Webelos II"))))))`

This is the IFS statement

`=IFS(J4="K","Lion", J4="1","Tiger", J4="2","Wolf", J4="3","Bear", J4="4","Webelos I", J4="5","Webelos II")`

It ONLY works right if I punch in K.  I do not get a proper response when I punch in 1, 2, etc.  What am I missing here?  I am having to do this in google sheets for others to be able to use.  I am getting the same or similar errors when I try it in excel as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(J5="K","Lion", IF(J5=1,"Tiger", IF(J5=2,"Wolf", IF(J5=3,"Bear", IF(J5=4,"Webelos I", IF(J5=5,"Webelos II", 0))))))
```

You were inputting the Integers as Strings.  Unless Excel is reading the numerical values as strings, your original formula will not work.

Comment: AHH thank you.  This fixed it. I was racking my brain and KNEW that it was something simple, but I just couldn't see it.  I guess all I need was some new eyes.  lol once again thanks.